# Is there a way to view my repository's remotes' URLs in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlens

In VS Code there is a source control panel. VS Code picks up and initializes the repository correctly when I open the root project folder (the directory that has the .git folder).

However, how do I see the repository settings? I can't find any options in the source control panel or the menu items. I would like to see what repository I'm working with.

I created a new repository and folder and have two directories for my project. VS Code is picking up both in the VS Code welcome screen and I've opened the wrong folder a few times now. I don't want to delete the old folder yet until I make sure the new folder is up to date and running correctly.

[image]

I've also installed two git extensions and I haven't found any repository information.

Here is from GitLens:
[image]

Basically, I would like to be able to see the ***repository URL*** that VS Code is pulling from.

I know I can open the git directory and see settings there. Because of a [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75495232/how-to-remove-or-modify-a-repository-from-vscode) I want to make sure VS Code is working with the correct folder.

Comment: Just `git remote -v` or view your `.git/config` file?

Comment: @user Thanks. That is helpful. I'll give those a try. There are people I work with and myself included that don't know all the inner workings of git.

Comment: I wouldn't really call using a _user-facing_ git command an "inner working of git" :P

Comment: It sounds like you just want to see the _remote_, in which case the command "Git: Remove Remote" (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_remotes - it's within "Remote" in your first screenshot and) will list all configured remotes. That's also presumably where "Open Repository on Remote" would take you in the second.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, no- I don't think there is a built-in way to view a repository's remotes' URLs in VS Code.

But not everything has to be done through VS Code. You can just run `git remote -v`, which will list a repository's remotes and their push and pull urls.

But in the interest of answering the question that was asked, technically, you can open the `.git/config` file in an editor tab, which will show similar info. The `files.exclude` setting has `"**/.git": true` in it by default, so to open that file in VS Code, you either have to change the settings to unhide it, or use the `File: Open File...` command / action and find it in your operating system / desktop environment's native file explorer application (an dyou may even need to toggle a setting there to "show hidden files" to be able to see it there as well).

The last option is to look for an extension that does this or create one.